# conectivity problem

Tags: ping, iptables, traceroute

I have 2 PCs (anuin and hed), both running Linux that are connected via ethernet (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.3).

Both PCs can ping each other.

anuin is connected to the internet via an USB-stick (device ppp0).

What I want is hed to access the internet via anuin.

That should be very easy but it seems I am being very stupid...

**Here is my routing table on hed:**

```
hed>sudo route 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         anuin           0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

hed>ping anuin
PING anuin (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from anuin (192.168.1.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.218 ms
64 bytes from anuin (192.168.1.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.191 ms
^C
```

**On anuin I have flushed all iptables-rules and just added a masquerading rule:**

```
anuin> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

anuin>  cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

anuin> sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Unfortunately it does not work when I try:**

```
hed> ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 8.8.8.8 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 8.8.8.8 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 8.8.8.8 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C

hed> traceroute anuin
traceroute to anuin (192.168.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  anuin (192.168.1.1)  0.203 ms  0.119 ms  0.450 ms

hed> traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)  3003.607 ms !H  3003.600 ms !H  3003.592 ms !H
```

This is what I don't get: Even when the masquerading does not work - should I not at least see the one hop to the default gateway (anuin).

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

What does `ip route get 8.8.8.8` say? If it's the wrong answer, there might be old forwading information cached from prior connection attempts.
    `ip route flush cache`
should be the remedy in that case.